# What is the syntax for creating a local (stack allocated) reference to a block in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'd like to create a local reference to a block to be handled differently depending on the execution context.  Normally I would define a special block type and assign the block to that type, but this is more of one-off situation and doesn't really merit a special type declaration.  What is the syntax for creating a local reference to a block without using a custom type definition?

Answer (score 3):

Use the same general syntax used when defining a custom type for a block, for example:

```
void (^myLocalBlock)(void) = ^{ printf("Buy low, sell high.\n"); };
myLocalBlock();
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), myLocalBlock);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), myLocalBlock);
```

For more information about block declaration syntax see:

http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/